# Генератор yield

Tags: python, yield

Пример из изучаемой мною книжки

```py
def fibonacci_generator():
    a = b = 1
    while True:
        yield a 
        a, b = b, a + b
        print(a, b) #поможет лучше понять работу
fib = fibonacci_generator()

for i in fib:
    if i > 100:
        break
    else:
        print('Generated:', i)
```

Что в данном коде выполняет функция yield? В книге написано - "Она [генераторная инструкция], начинается с ключевого слова yield и определяет объект-генератор (то есть переменную a?), который возвращается оператору (print?), вызвавшему функцию. Когда генераторная инструкция исполняется, состояние объекта генератора "замораживается" и сохраняется. Объект, возвращаемый генераторной инструкцией, может быть присвоен переменной (это мы сделали на 7 строке кода?)."
Но я так и не понял, как это отражается в результате кода?

Я пытаюсь понять работу кода сопоставив код с результатом его выполнения. Вот несколько строк результата:

```py
Generated: 1
1 2
Generated: 1
2 3
Generated: 2
3 5
Generated: 3
5 8
Generated: 5
8 13
...
```

Что после операций a, b = b, a + b становится содержимым функции fibonacci_generator? Результат суммы a и b? Переменная а на второй итерации равна 2, потому что "при этом она сохраняет состояние своего последнего вызова и при следующем вызове продолжает работу с той же точки."? Почему, к примеру, на первой итерации, вывод переменной b отображает 2, ведь сумма а +  b просто какое-то, ничему не присвоенное выражение?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. ***`yield` определяет объект-генератор (то есть переменную a?)***

   Нет, под объектом генератором подразумевается вся функция целиком.

   Она преобразуется в генератор, если в её теле присутствует инструкция `yield`.
   Переменная `a` — это то, что будет генерироваться и возвращаться.
2. ***который возвращается оператору (print?)***

   Нет, генератор в Вашем коде возвращается и присваивается переменной `fib`:

   ```py
   fib = fibonacci_generator()
   print(type(fib))  # <class 'generator'>
   ```
3. ***Объект, возвращаемый генераторной инструкцией, может быть присвоен переменной (это мы сделали на 7 строке кода?)***

   Нет, в 7 строке кода Вы возвращаете новое сгенерированное значение и замораживаете генератор, а присваивание этого значения переменной неявно происходит в 9 строке кода:

   ```py
   for i in fib:
       ...
   ```

   Инструкция `for` на каждой итерации будет присваивать `i` какое-то значение.
   Для этого она будет обращаться к функции (через методы итерирования).

   Вы вручную можете получать новые значения из генератора, используя функцию `next`:

   ```py
   i = next(fib)
   ```

   Попробуйте отказаться от цикла `for` и использовать только инструкцию выше, чтобы лучше понять, как генератор возвращает новое значение.
4. ***`a, b = b, a + b`***

   Это сокращённая запись кортежного присваивания:

   ```py
   (a, b) = (b, a + b)
   ```

   Элементы из левого кортежа будут сопоставлены с элементами из правого (количество должно быть одинаково) и им будут присвоены соответствующие значения.

Answer (score 1):

```
a, b = c, d
```

это почти то же самое, что

```
a = c
b = d
```

только вычисляется не последовательно, а справа налево.

Чтобы поменять местами два значения можно написать

```
a, b = b, a
```

У тебя почти то же самое, но вместо второй переменной сумма:

```
a, b = b, a + b
```

Answer (score 1):

Генераторы это очень интересная штука. https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions
Вот документация. Простым языком: `yield` - это выражение, которое используется при создании функции-генераторы или асинхронного генератора. Еще проще: генератор - это конструкция, в которой реализован протокол итератора, т.е. любой генератор = итерируемая последовательность, которую можно перебирать в цикле, как списки, только значения она возвращает вызовом метода `next()`, значит - не сразу, а последовательно, за каждое обращение.